# Struggling to use jQuery change to show specific div/h2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

fairly new to js so hope this isn't a silly question. I have spent a while scouring the forum but can't find an answer to my specific need.

I have a dropdown box, what I need to happen is when an option is selected a certain div/h2 to show, but I seem to get all or nothing ... any pointers would be appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Change jq</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<select name="sweets">
  <option value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>
  <option value="Cakes">Cakes</option>
  <option value="Caramel">Caramel</option>
  <option value="Fudge">Fudge</option>
</select>
<div></div>

<script>
$( "select" )
  .change(function () {
    var str = "";

    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
      str += $( this ).val() + "";
      echo str;
    });
    $( "div" ).text( str );
    $('.whoToSee').show();
    //$('h2:contains(.str)') . show();
  })
  .change();
</script>


<div class='whoToSee' style='display:none'>

 <h2 class="Chocolate">Chocolate</h2>
<strong>Who to see: </strong>Bob

<strong>Advice:</strong>Eat less of it
</div>

<div class='whoToSee' style='display:none'>
<h2 class="Cakes">Cakes/h2>

<strong>Who to see:</strong>Sally
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First Hide the Div you want to show. Then, you need to invoke a jquery function when the specific option is selected. This function should just toggle the state of the div from hide to show. (https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show) Got it from w3 schools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a few things pop out here -

1) `<h2 class="Cakes">Cakes/h2>`, you're missing `<` in front of the closing h2.

2) The main problem with your script not working is that `echo` isn't a javascript function. Removing it will fix the issue of nothing showing up. The reason for the behaviour you're seeing is Javascript will stop processing your scripts when it encounters an error.

3) Your script has this line: `$( "div" ).text( str );` - this will change the text in **every** div to the value of `str`. So when you switch to Cakes for instance, you'll just get all your divs populated with Cakes. If this is what you want, great. Additionally, the selector `".whoToSee"` will select both of your divs and show them.

You can see what this looks like with the changes here: https://jsfiddle.net/Kolichikov/hn6zjxeu/

If you want to show just one of the divs, you can give each an id (for example, id="Chocolate", id="Cakes"). You can see the change [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Kolichikov/hn6zjxeu/5/). (Note also, I've added a call to the jquery function `hide` to hide the currently selected div).

Comment: Thanks Kolichikov very much! 
Re 1&2 .. they were just me trying things in the end, but that is good to know that js just stops if there is wrong code there, didn't know that!

The second link you gave me is exactly what I need to do! I will learn from that!

Thanks for your help!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either using .show()/.hide(), or by using css property. Here as you using style="display:none" in HTML so instead of .show use below code.
At the beginning of your code add document.ready as below

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('.whoToSee').css("display", "none")
})
```

And in your function where you writing $('.whoToSee').show() instead use $('.whoToSee').css("display" , "block")